# proof that e is the sum of the reciprocals of factorials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Ok so we know that:

e= lim n→∞(1+1/n)^n.

and we know by binomial theorem, that

lim n→∞ of $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (1/n)^k = (1+ \frac{1}{n})$

To simplify further to $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = e$

we must evaluate the following limit:

n→∞${n \choose k} \frac{1}{n^k}=\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{k! n^k}$

and this is supposed to equal to $\frac{1}{k!}$

This is not clear to me algebriacally, so may some one please clear this up step by step so I can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!},$$where with $k$ fixed$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)=\frac{1^{k-1}}{k!}=\frac{1}{k!}.$$

Comment: Yes but why is (n choose k)/n^k = 1/k! ?

Comment: @GLaDOS It's not; it's $k!^{-1}\prod_{1\le j\le k-1}(1-j/n)$.

Comment: Why is that product equal to n!/n^k(n-k)!  then?

Comment: @GLaDOS Because $n!/(n-k)!=n\cdots(n-k+1)$.

Comment: What I am unclear about is why: n^k(n)(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) = (1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)...(1-(k-1)/n)

Comment: @GLaDOS Again, you've missed a factor. I suggest you work through the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

We may prove that by considering the Maclaurin series of the exponential function.$$f(x)=e^x=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$
$$\therefore f(1)=e=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}=1+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+\cdots$$

Comment: Prove the maclaurin series

Comment: Maclaurin series is the Taylor series centered at $x=0$. Maclaurin series of a function $f(x)$ is defined as $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ where $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$. You can figure it out for $e^x$ which is an extremely easy exercise.

Comment: Prove the taylor series

Comment: You may refer to this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: It only includes a definition, but ok. I guess I can't ask much from you then.

Comment: @GLaDOS the Taylor series itself is defined as an approximation to the main function $f(x)$. For a better visual intuitive introduction to the Taylor series, refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4&t=481s

Comment: @GLaDOS You sure can ask what you're unclear on but you also have to try to research and reinforce the basics at your end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_0 + c_1n + \cdots  + c_kn^k}{n^k} = c_k$$

for any constants $c_i$, we get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_0 + c_1n + \cdots  + c_kn^k}{k!n^k} = \frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_0 + c_1n + \cdots  + c_kn^k}{n^k} = \frac{c_k}{k!}$$

Note that your numerator, when expanded, is a monic polynomial with degree $k$, which fits the above with $c_k = 1$.